# optimized query to left join with the date range when master table have 80M records

Tags: mysql

Okay so here is the solution which is working as inteded the only issue if there is no rows for that date in detail table then its shows no rows for any ProductionStatusNo and for the date but I still need those rows with the zero value.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS date_range;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE date_range AS
        SELECT DATE('2023-12-01') + INTERVAL (n-1) DAY AS StatusDate
        FROM (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n 
          FROM detail 
          LIMIT 31  
        ) AS StatusDate;
        
        SELECT * FROM date_range order by StatusDate ;
        
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS date_range_production_status ; 
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE date_range_production_status AS
        SELECT d.StatusDate as StatusDate,
        p.Status as ProductionStatus,
        p.Id as ProductionStatusNo
        FROM date_range d
        CROSS JOIN productionstatus p WHERE p.Id not in ( 0,1) ;
SELECT
         COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS c,
         ed.MaxPrductionStatusNo,
         ed.StatusDate,
         ed.ProductionFacility
        FROM
         (
             SELECT
                 dr.StatusDate,
                 detail.UniqueFormId,
                 MAX(detail.productionStatusNo) AS MaxPrductionStatusNo,
                 ProductionFacility
             FROM
                 detail
             INNER JOIN date_range_production_status dr ON detail.StatusDate <= dr.StatusDate and detail.ProductionStatusNo!=1
             GROUP BY dr.StatusDate, detail.UniqueFormId,detail.ProductionFacility
         ) AS ed
        GROUP BY
         ed.MaxPrductionStatusNo,ed.StatusDate 
         ORDER BY StatusDate,MaxPrductionStatusNo, ProductionFacility;
```

so in case there is no rows lets say for '2023-12-01' still then result should show something like that for that day

[image: output required if there is no rows given in master table for all the status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you require reporting of all dates, then you need to revise the order of tables as see here:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
  SELECT CURDATE() AS CurrentDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_SUB(CurrentDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  FROM dates
  WHERE DATE_SUB(CurrentDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) >= LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   )
SELECT
 COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS c,
 ed.MaxPrductionStatusNo,
 ed.CurrentDate
FROM dates 
LEFT JOIN  (
     SELECT
         dr.CurrentDate,
         detail.UniqueFormId,
         MAX(detail.productionStatusNo) AS MaxPrductionStatusNo
     FROM
         detail
     INNER JOIN dates dr ON detail.StatusDate <= dr.CurrentDate
     GROUP BY dr.CurrentDate, detail.UniqueFormId
 ) AS ed ON dates.CurrentDate = ed.CurrentDate
GROUP BY
 ed.MaxPrductionStatusNo,
 ed.CurrentDate
```

---

The original response (as adopted in the revised question):

I suggest forming a table of dates (using a CTE) from today to the first of the same month, then join that table. Note a left join isn't required as count will ignore nulls:

```
CREATE TABLE detail (
   UniqueFormId INT PRIMARY KEY,
   productionStatusNo INT,
   StatusDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO detail (UniqueFormId, productionStatusNo, StatusDate) VALUES
(1, 1, '2023-01-01'),
(2, 2, '2023-01-02'),
(3, 3, '2023-01-03'),
(4, 4, '2023-01-04'),
(5, 5, '2023-01-05');
```

---

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
  SELECT CURDATE() AS CurrentDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_SUB(CurrentDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  FROM dates
  WHERE DATE_SUB(CurrentDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) >= LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
)
SELECT
 COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS c,
 ed.MaxPrductionStatusNo,
 ed.CurrentDate
FROM
 (
     SELECT
         dr.CurrentDate,
         detail.UniqueFormId,
         MAX(detail.productionStatusNo) AS MaxPrductionStatusNo
     FROM
         detail
     INNER JOIN dates dr ON detail.StatusDate <= dr.CurrentDate
     GROUP BY dr.CurrentDate, detail.UniqueFormId
 ) AS ed
GROUP BY
 ed.MaxPrductionStatusNo,
 ed.CurrentDate
```

| c | MaxPrductionStatusNo | CurrentDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-01-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 2024-01-01 |
| 1 | 3 | 2024-01-01 |
| 1 | 4 | 2024-01-01 |
| 1 | 5 | 2024-01-01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GAbJxSrk)

Comment: its miss the rows for '2024-01-01' , if there is no row for that in detail but I still need that with the c as 0.

Comment: and also I have 80 million records so that      INNER JOIN dates dr ON detail.StatusDate <= dr.CurrentDate
 taking too much time , but in the case of earlier where clause it works in less then one minute .

Comment: If you want missing dates use `from dates` and left join the detail table. When you do that you will need to use the join condition otherwise you recreate the missing dates issue again

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/dMf1gRpS for listing all the dates

Comment: Btw. Using the join condition is no less efficient than the same predicate in a where clause, except that if you adopt my latest suggestion it will return all wanted dates.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/UpuTvVKH see here I changed some dates and value for ProducitonStatusNo

Comment: Ok, seen it. Is this closer to your solution now?

Comment: Yes its close to my solution , only issue here is that when I run this query on detail table which have 80 M records its like its runs forever

Comment: Indexing the columns involved in joins, aggregation, and date range filtering can assist in optimizing performance. Study the explain plan to look for improvements. If in doubt open a new question for optimisation advice be sure to include explain plan and the query plus any current indexing details